# How can parse the dynamic json with newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json

I have this json:

```
"{'service_list': [], 'session_id': '234234DSSF', 'user':
{'basic_info': {'recharge_deposit': 0.0, 'status': 'Recharged',
'user_id': 8, 'deposit': 0.0, 'isp_id': 0, 'group_id': 5,
'creation_date': '2017-04-19 08:11:26.882558', 'nearest_exp_date':
'2017-05-19 08:56:00', 'group_name': 'IRN-U2'}, 'id': 8, 'is_prepaid':
True, 'attrs': {'normal_password': 'subh1', 'real_first_login':
'1492592160', 'normal_username': 'subh1', 'user_id': 8, 'first_login':
'1492592160'}}, 'event': 'first_login', 'event_datetime': '2017-05-10
10:00:00', 'remote_ip': ['127.0.0.1']}"
```

and want to parse with this c# code:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);
```

but get this error on that line:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path
>   'user.is_prepaid', line 1, position 317

How can i solve that?

Comment: How are you saving X? is is possibel you are passing a string and not json?

Comment: @JoshAdams yes my friend pass that string

Comment: You need to be using double quotes instead of single quotes for your json fields and values. Use jsonlint.com to validate your json.

Comment: validate your json first and then check if you need to submit a question

Comment: if you report it as a bug, you can also mention that single quotes `'` are not valid JSON (should be double quotes `"`), and can't be parsed with for example JavaScript `JSON.parse`

Comment: This is not JSON, post missing real [MCVE] and really just typo. Which close reason you'd prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element:

```
'is_prepaid': True
```

needs to be changed to

```
'is_prepaid': true
```

for it to be parsed properly.

Comment: thanks ,but that string coming from other server,and i can not change that

Comment: Can't you use regex on it to replace True with true before passing?

Comment: You might need to edit the string before you parse it. Something like `x = x.Replace(": True,", ": true,");` (and the same for false).

Comment: .. and you should report the invalid generated json as  bug.